# DFT Filter Banks

Tags: fft, filters, sampling, ifft, filter-bank

i have a doubt about DFT filter banks. For example I have $M=4$ channels and a filter with cut-off frequency of $0.25$ right.
The prototype filter $H_0$ is a low-pass centered around $0$ ok. The second filter $H_1$ is centered around $0.5\pi$, the third around $\pi$ and the last $H_3$ (cyan colored) is centered around $3\pi/2$. My doubt is what do i do with $H_3$ such that the bandwidth is from $0$ to $\pi$ (0 20MHz)??? [image]

S.

Comment: Sorry, but i Know that negative frequencies are just Mathematical artifice, i don't manage to understand why i have to select a Channel into negative frequencies. I'm grateful if you clarify me this concept.

Comment: Based on your comment I added some information to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're doing everything correctly. For an $M$-channel DFT filter bank, the impulse response of the $m^{th}$ filter is given by

$$h_m[n]=h_0[n]e^{j\frac{2\pi m}{M}},\qquad 0<m<M\tag{1}$$

where $h_0[n]$ is the prototype filter. For $M=4$, $h_3[n]$ is indeed centered at $\omega=3\pi /2$. Note that due to the $2\pi$-periodicity of discrete-time Fourier transforms, this is equivalent to a center frequency of $\omega=-\pi/2$. So the right half of your plot just shows the negative frequencies, and if your input signal is real-valued, your actual bandwidth is indeed just $[0,\pi]$.

Note that if the prototype filter $h_0[n]$ is real-valued, the filters $h_1[n]$ and $h_3[n]$ are just complex conjugates of each other:

$$h_3[n]=h_0[n]e^{j3\pi/2}=h_0[n]e^{-j\pi/2}=h_1^*[n]\tag{2}$$

If the input signal is real-valued, the outputs of these two filters can be obtained from each other by complex conjugation. So in this case the filter $h_3[n]$ is redundant. This is the same as with a standard DFT of a real-valued signal, where (approximately) half the points are redundant due to symmetry. Nevertheless, depending on the implementation it is often cheaper to compute all output values, even the redundant ones.

Comment: Ok, thus M=4, but in reality the bandwidth is divided into 3 channels, right?

Comment: @Stefano: Yes, for real signals there are 3 non-redundant channels.